# How to obtain value of Perl regex match variable with index stored in another variable?

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine that takes as input the a position in a string, and should return the word found at that position. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $num=2;
my $val=getMatch($num);

sub getMatch {
    my ($num)=@_;

    my $str='a b c';
    $str=~ /(\S+)\s(\S+)/;

    my $res;
    eval "$res=\$$num";
    return $res
}
```

But this gives error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $res in concatenation (.) or string at ./p.pl line 16.
```

(I am trying to return `$i` where `i` is a value stored in another variable..)

Comment: Seems like I forgot to put a slash in front of `$res` : `eval "\$res=\$$num"`.. But maybe there is simpler ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do:

```
my $num=2;
my $val=getMatch($num);
say $val;
sub getMatch {
    my ($num)=@_;
    my $str='a b c';
    my @res = $str =~ /(\S+)\s(\S+)/;
    return $res[$num-1];
}
```

**Output:**

```
b
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `@+` and `@-` special variables, documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), like this:

```
sub getMatch {
    my ($num)=@_;

    my $str='a b c';
    $str=~ /(\S+)\s(\S+)/;

    return substr( $str, $-[$num], $+[$num] - $-[$num] );
}
print getMatch(1), "\n";
print getMatch(2), "\n";
```

Or you could adjust your regex like this:

```
sub getMatch {
    my $num = shift() - 1;
    my $str='a b c';
    $str=~ /(?:\S+\s){$num}(\S+)/;

    return $1;
}
print getMatch(1), "\n";
print getMatch(2), "\n";
```

...which has the advantage of producing only a single capture group.

Another option is to just split on space:

```
sub getMatch {
    my ($num)=@_;
    my $str='a b c';
    return ( split /\s/, $str )[$num-1];
}

print getMatch(1), "\n";
print getMatch(2), "\n";
```

...but that last solution is more permissive as to what it will match; it doesn't explicitly require two or more non-space items separated by a space.  If `3` were passed in, it would return 'c'.

This last one produces results similar to the split version but using a regex.  I'd probably prefer the split because it's more straightforward, but I provide this just for edification:

```
sub getMatch {
    my ($num)=@_;
    my $str='a b c';
    return ( $str =~ m/(\S+)(?=\s|$)/g )[$num-1];
}

print getMatch(1), "\n";
print getMatch(2), "\n";
```